# Video is not showing on VideoView but I can hear its sound

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

- On my button click I wrote the following code for playing video from
  my **SDCARD (mp4).**

  ```
  video_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
  video_view.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
  video_view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
  video_view.start();
  ```
- I can play recorded video from SDCARD in player.
- But when I run it on my application in videoview I can hear only sound.
- **Problem :** **I am not able to see the video.**

### ---- I tried following SO link but still no luck ----

- [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13864118/1367157)
- [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11805205/1367157)
- Is anybody ever faced this kind of problem ? If yes then how can it solve it ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I've tried every method above, but none of them could work.

Finally, I tried to call this function, then the video appeared.

```
video_view.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Hope this also works for you.

Comment: I was just having with problem with API 19 Kitkat only, it worked everywhere else. Setting this fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Tried everything under the Sun and this finally worked -- thank ya.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only issues is that now you can't put anything on top of the video, for example subtitles :(

Comment: Any fix on this to put something above the video (subtitle, mute control...)? This is more of a hack than the correct solution!

Comment: @SeaStar  video_view.setZOrderOnTop(true);  method not found for ScalableVideoView and ScalableVideoView is extends TextureView, Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you did set a background-color for the VideoView, try removing that backround-color instead of setting the z-order-on-top.

Comment: I have an overlay I use, so I hide the videoview and then on click event make the videoview visible, but it was not playing. But once I set the zOrderOnTop(true) it was visible.

Answer (score 16):

SOLUTION 1:

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

this will set the videoview to the top layer; In other words: block everything under it.

SOLUTION 2:

```
videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

SOLUTION 3:

sometimes this is related about your apptheme; In my case, I changed the apptheme from `@style/AppTheme` to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it may be help you...

Answer (score 2):

Can you give this a try?

```
video_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(video_view);
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(video_view); //you probably don't need this
video_view.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
video_view.setMediaController(mediaController);
video_view.start();
```

Comment: Still my problem is there !!

Comment: Ok I'm not sure how this would make a difference but, can you try with `video_view.requestFocus();` just before `video_view.start();`

Comment: Not yet . @Pawan Kumar

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, my video view resized to the expected video resolution but there is nothing on the screen. I tried to use above mentioned solutions but nothing worked.

I tried to set the visibility and that worked, not sure why. This might help someone who come across this post and is facing an issue like me

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.viewLiveStream);
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Here is my XML, not sure why visibility was an issue.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_bg1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/btnStreaming"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_streaming" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtStreamingUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2" />
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/viewLiveStream"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/play"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
~
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue except that I was adding my video view programmatically. I noticed while inspecting the view hierarchy that the parent ViewGroup had it's layer type set to software.

Since the codebase I work on is shared and I didn't notice that the layer type was being setting to software in a subclass of the parent ViewGroup.

So try setting the parent's views layer type to None or Hardware

```
// Remove this if your parent ViewGroup has this set
//setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

// Or set this layer type if the above is not present
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
video_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
video_view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
video_view.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
video_view.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video_view.start();
video_view.videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

put the setZorderOnTop(true) method after you started the videoView, not before.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was placing the VideoView control at top of the layout and no matter
if you set the visibility property.

This work for me on a S6 with Android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

```
<VideoView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
android:id="@+id/myVideo"/>


public class Videoplay extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplay);
         VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);

        String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

        Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, "Loading Teaser",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
          vidView.start();   
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);

        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);


    }
```

Here I am playing the video from one of the links..
It works perfectly for me.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The black screen and audio playing happened with me when I did not release the MediaPlayer object. When you play a video in Activity with media player you have to release it when activity is destroyed. And when you open it again a new instance of media player will be created and use the already released resources.

MediaPlayer.release();

Answer (score 0):

I tried all above answers but did not get success after observing some code, i request focus for my video view.
And It is now working on all devices,
Hope this will work for some Devs!!

```
private var mediaController: MediaController? = null
private fun prepareVideo() {
    val uri = Uri.fromFile(File(recordedVideoPath))
    mediaController = MediaController(this)
    mediaController?.setAnchorView(videoView)
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
    videoView.requestFocus()
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
    videoView.seekTo(2)
    videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true)

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener {
        try {
            mediaController?.show(0)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            System.out.println("Error in Video")
        }
    }
    videoView.setOnErrorListener { _, _, _ ->
        true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but I find out that It was caused by the media file. My video file has 1080x1920 resolution. My device doesn't support height >= 1080 so VideoView has sound only.
I use mmpeg to convert supported resolution
This is command i use, you can convert it to any code with library:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale='-1:min(1080,ih)'" output.mp4
```

Answer (score -7):

I think you use bad mp4 format. Uses Android specific mp4 format!!!

Comment: Can you explain more about why it's a problem?