# How to play video URL inside android webview

Tags: android, video, webview

I want to play video url inside my application webview but when i am run the application it showing only white screen .
i had read some post on this and i have used that code but video is not playing in webview it launch device player but my requirement not this .

please help me if some one already done this . 
my code is here :-

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4");
    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Testing URL is working in browser .

Answer (score 20):

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
```

> also set in manifist file

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: This is not playing video directly in webview, rather its opening browser which is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: It is playing video which comes from URL and it's opening in webview . Can you explain why it's not a solution . If you have some better idea please share @Muhammad

Comment: `pluginState` - deprecated, plugins are not supported in Kitkat or later

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old issue, I had the same problem some days back and surfing across internet I found this complete source that helped me a lot, and now i want to share with others, maybe can help others like me..

https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView

Answer (score 2):

If tried others anwsers no work,maybe you can try this:

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` and to enable plugins for your video add:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
     webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
  }  
  else {
     webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ siddharth not working only showing zoom button i am using version >4.0

Comment: THank you so much can i send my layout also

Comment: He bro, it's working in my device.By the way, have you added Internet permission ?? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: yes i have added , but in my device only showing white screen

Comment: Can you check with other url like some youtube url?

Comment: Yes Siddharth you tube is blocked in my office but when i use this url in my phone browser its wotking

Answer (score 1):

You need to load an HTML document that embeds the video inside of it, instead of the video directly. To play inline video in WebView using the `<video>` tag you must also ensure the hardware acceleration is enabled in your application (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old question but this works:

```
    //Here Im loading the html file from disk
    String html_file = LoadData(file.getAbsolutePath());

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.reload();
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadData(html_file, "text/html; charset="utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Use base64 encoded video data as your `video` source:

```
//html_file
<video controls>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/webm;base64,MY_BASE64_ENCODED VIDEO_HERE">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was the solution

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: please add details to the answer

Answer (score 0):

No you can't play the video by link in this case. To do this you should create an *RTSP* connection then you can play the video through an RTSP url in `Webview`. You can retrieve an RTSP connection from a server like Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
{
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setMinimumFontSize(10);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);         
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, vUrl, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck with this issue. I got correct response from server, but couldn`t play video. After long time I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650483/video-is-not-showing-on-videoview-but-i-can-hear-its-sound/20120750#20120750). Maybe, in future this link will be invalid. So, here is my correct code

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("Your link should be in this place "); 
mVideoView.setVideoURI(video); 

mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true); //Very important line, add it to Your code
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
   // here write another part of code, which provides starting the video
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Kotlin**, this code can be useful:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    val url = "https://..."
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)

    webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
    webView.settings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false
   
    webView.loadUrl(url)
```