# How to show video in webView on Android

Tags: android, video, webview

I want to show text, image and video in my application. For this issue I use `webView` because I should show image and video between texts.
**for set `webView` I write this codes:**

```
    WebSettings settings = post_content_web.getSettings();
    post_content_web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    String myCustomStyleString = "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: " +
            "url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/iran_sans_mobile.ttf\")}body,* {font-family: MyFont; font-size: " +
            "medium;text-align: justify;}</style>";

    post_content_web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", myCustomStyleString + "<div style=\"direction:rtl\">"
            + title + "\n\n" + content + "</div>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I use **Embed** code from video, such as this :

```
<div id="14915658601813975"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/hdvzs?data[rnddiv]=14915658601813975&data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>
```

My application shows video frame (border) and video thumbnail but when I click on video to play, does't show any video and just show black screen!!!!

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play video URL inside android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322057/how-to-play-video-url-inside-android-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support the video available in div tag(`<div>`),
You will have to add some extra properties for WebView Settings.

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
```

I had the same issue, and adding **this snippet** solved *BLACK SCREEN*.

May this helps you too!

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!