# Android Videoview is not displaying video at all only sound is heard

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-videoview

Videoview is not showing video but is playing sound,It shows Black screen every time. I am running Android 4.0.I am running this on emulator.

This is my xml file.

```
<VideoView
android:id="@+id/myVideo"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:visibility="visible"/>
```

.java file

```
VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
String vidAddress ="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";

Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView); 
vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
vidView.setZOrderOnTop(false); 

vidView.start();
```

Please help I am stuck on it from one week. Searched a lot but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a litle old but Iam posting this update just in case someone run with the same issue that I did. This is also an improved answer to the one above.

Anyway, What you have to do is to put the: vidView.setZOrderOnTop(true);  statement ***AFTER*** the `vidView.start();` statement. I was having the same problem with the white/gray screen showing(that you mentioned on the comments)  even though the video was playing in the background. I think that is because your setZOrderOnTop was set before you start the video.If you start the video first then set the `setZOrderOnTop` will fix it for you like it did for me. Hope that helps.

```
vidView.start();
vidView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

Comment: vidView.setZOrderOnTop(true) by itself didn't work me. Moving this line after vidView.start() was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

solution 1:

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

this will set the videoview to the top layer; In other words: block everything under it.

solution 2:

```
videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

solution 3:

sometimes this is related about your apptheme;
In my case, I changed the apptheme from "@style/AppTheme" to "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

change vidView.setZOrderOnTop(false) to true so it will be `vidView.setZOrderOnTop(true);`

Reference :  [Video is not showing on VideoView but i can hear its sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650483/video-is-not-showing-on-videoview-but-i-can-hear-its-sound)
`

Comment: When i change it to true i.e vidView.setZOrderOnTop(true);                                         then the whole screen turned grey....I am running this on emulator.

Comment: I have sort it on my own.The emulator is not showing video but the video is working fine on the real device.

Comment: @MominaNisar - Thankyou for that. Struggling with my emulator since long :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and solved it with the following:

```
videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom VideoPlayer by extending VideoView class and use it:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends VideoView {

public VideoPlayer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        TyrooLog.i(TAG, "onMeasure");
        int width = getDefaultSize(videoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getDefaultSize(videoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (videoWidth > 0 && videoHeight > 0) {
            if (videoWidth * height > width * videoHeight) {
                TyrooLog.i(TAG, "video too tall, correcting");
                height = width * videoHeight / videoWidth;
            } else if (videoWidth * height < width * videoHeight) {
                TyrooLog.i(TAG, "video too wide, correcting");
                width = height * videoWidth / videoHeight;
            } else {
                TyrooLog.i(TAG, "aspect ratio is correct: " + width+"/"+height+"="+mVideoWidth+"/"+mVideoHeight);
            }
        }
        TyrooLog.i(TAG, "setting size: " + width + 'x' + height);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```