# Video from resources is not displaying

Tags: android, video, android-resources, android-videoview

I'm trying to display an mp4 video from the app resources inside a `VideoView`, referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061887/1638739) and [this tutorial](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/06/how-to-play-video-from-resources.html) I used the following way:

```
// make the videoView visible
storyVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// set Video Preferences
storyVideo.requestFocus();
storyVideo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
// get & set the video URI
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.story_media4);
storyVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
// Start The Video
storyVideo.start();
```

where story_media4 is stored in the raw file in resources:

[image]

Comment: Try to remove the black background. And is there any error displayed ?

Comment: @ElMaravilla there is no errors I'm getting from that, also I don't think the background can do anything according to that, I'm already setting the same preferences in videos with network URLs and they are working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the video was displaying but not showing, with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120750/1638739), I could display the video after setting `video_view.setZOrderOnTop(true);` on both video URI setting and video prepared listener method:

```
// set Video Preferences
storyVideo.requestFocus();
storyVideo.setZOrderOnTop(true);
// get & set the video URI
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.story_media4);
storyVideo.setVideoURI(uri);
// when the video is ready for display
storyVideo.setOnPreparedListener(onVideoPrepared);

private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener onVideoPrepared = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        storyVideo.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        // to start the video
        storyVideo.start();
    }
};
```

---

Update:
For the above method, the video is going on Top of all of the views, if -for a reason- you want the video to be covered by one or more views (like sticker or description text) the best way is to set the background of the video to TRANSPARENT :

```
storyVideo.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `storyVideo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` .
I test your code and remove `setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` and fix this problem.
Please test below code for `OnPreparedListener()` :

```
 videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Log.i("LOG","Video test");
        }
    });
```

please remove `videoView.start()` in your `onPrepared` and test with `Log()`.

Comment: actually in my case it is a VideoView not a MediaPlayer

Comment: you have a point here, it's not about the Black, but setting it to TRANSPARENT also is doing the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Videoplay extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplay);


        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);

        String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

        Toast.makeText(Videoplay.this, "Loading Teaser",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

        vidView.start();


        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);

        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);


    }
```